# Setting DataContext to xaml.cs file

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8, datacontext

I've got a `Grid` and a component inside it.
The `Grid` has a custom `DataContext` while the children has to use the default `.xaml.cs` file.

Of course, changing the `DataContext` for the parent control changes it also for the children.

So I need to set the children's `DataContext` to the `xaml.cs` file.

I'm trying using `DataContext="{Binding}"` but it's not working.

How can I do that?

EDIT:
Here's my code based on the replies

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass"
x:Name="MyName"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:lsp="clr-namespace:LSPlugins"
xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:LSPlugins.Utilities"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"> 

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <utils:ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
        <lsp:MyModel x:Key="MyModel" x:Name="MyModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{StaticResource MyModel}" Background="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}" Opacity="{Binding Path=BackgroundOpacity}">        
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding PresenterContent}" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyName}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I've tried with both `Name` and `x:Name` but it's still not working and it throws this exception:

> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'PresenterContent' property not found on 'MyNamespace.MyModel' 'MyNamespace.MyModel' (HashCode=63183526). BindingExpression: Path='PresenterContent' DataItem='MyNamespace.MyModel' (HashCode=63183526); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'System.Object')..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by binding the page element itself to the DataContext property:

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=phoneApplicationPage}
```

Or, in the code-behind (i.e xaml.cs file):

```
yourElement.DataContext = this;
```

**EDIT:**

Or, you can set the `Content` with a `Binding` by setting the source there:

```
Content="{Binding PresenterContent, ElementName=MyName}"
```

Comment: I've edited the question with the new code. I'd like to avoid using the code-behind anyways

Comment: @StepTNT I would say that DataContext is set correctly in your code. The problem may be in the Content property. Where is PresenterContent defined?

Comment: The property is in the `xaml.cs` file and there's no typo or stuff like that. I'm adding the exception because it seems that the parser is trying to find the property in the model rather then using the `xaml.cs` context

Comment: I don't know this will solve your problem, but why don't you set the Background of Grid this way without setting DataContext? `Background="{Binding BackgroundColor, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource MyModel}}"`

Comment: The binding is not working as intended but at least this solved the exception and this means that I've got no DataContext problems. Thank you for this tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can name the parent control and then bind the children's DataContext using the ElementName:

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TheWindow}"
```